# ActiveMQ - How to reserve store space for some queues?

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm using **ActiveMQ** as messages server for external application, but also for my internal messages.

If my application is down for too long, external applications full ActiveMq server. But when I restart it, it can't consume messages because it can't send "internal" messages (my routes are transactional). So all the system is blocked.

Is there a way to reserve some store space for my internal messages? Or is-it possible to limit size of some queues?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a [destination policy](http://activemq.apache.org/per-destination-policies.html) and producer flow control to limit the maximum memory consumed by all or specific queues. In your activemq.xml you need to add a section like this:

```
<destinationPolicy>
    <policyMap>
        <policyEntries>
            <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="50mb" />
        </policyEntries>
    </policyMap>
</destinationPolicy>
```

The [destination wildcard](http://activemq.apache.org/wildcards.html) ">" will match all queues. You can change the pattern to match only those queues that you want the policy to affect.

Each queue affected by the policy will have set its memory limit to 50mb. This means that you need to take the number of queues into consideration to calculate the max memory consumed by the queues and whether it fits into the available VM heap space.

The policy only limits the amount of memory to use. The [temp- and file-store limits](http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html#ProducerFlowControl-Systemusage) can only be set globally for the broker, not on a per destination basis.

Comment: This peace of configuration means: "All queues must share 50 mb" or "Each queue must not contains more that 50mb"? And other question, I'm using persistent queue, "memoryLimit" isn't to limit space _in memory_ (and not _in storage_)?

Comment: Ok, I think that's answer my question: if I want to reserve some **store** space for some queues, I have to create another broker...

Comment: Dush, you don't.  I've updated @Ralf's answer with some addition detail

Answer (score 1):

*I tried to do this as an edit to the other answer but it was not approved*

You can limit the storage used by an individual queue using [per destination policies](http://activemq.apache.org/per-destination-policies.html).  Adjusting the `storeUsageHighWaterMark` property which defaults to 100%.  From the documentation:

`the tipping point at which a system usage store limit will cause a sent to block`

So your configuration would be something like:

```
<destinationPolicy>
  <policyMap>
    <policyEntries>
      <policyEntry queue=">" storeUsageHighWaterMark="75" producerFlowControl="true" >
      </policyEntry>
      <policyEntry queue="INTERNAL.>" storeUsageHighWaterMark="100" producerFlowControl="true">
      </policyEntry>
    </policyEntries>
  </policyMap>
</destinationPolicy>
```

This indicates that queues beginning with `INTERNAL.` can use 100% of the storage space before blocking.  Other queues will block once 75% of the storage space is in use.